# Are Azure File Service clients / objects threadsafe? Can they be cached?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-files

We have recently moved to Azure File Storage.  We use the `CloudFileClient` and `CloudFileShare` to access files.

Currently we create these on every call which seems inefficient.  Can any of these be cached, either at function level or created as a static instance (as you would a `HttpClient`)?

An example method we use

```
private async Task<CloudFile> GetFileRef(string directory, string filenameAndExtension)
{
    // Could this be static / cached?
    var client = this.storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

    // Could this be static / cached?
    var share = client.GetShareReference(this.azureFileShareReference);

    // Could this be static / cached?
    if (!await share.ExistsAsync())
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"Azure share {this.azureFileShareReference} does not exist");
    }

    // Could this be static / cached?
    var rootRef = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

    // Could this be static / cached?
    var dirRef = rootRef.GetDirectoryReference(directory);

    return dirRef.GetFileReference(filenameAndExtension);
}
```